# How to pass the data from a state to a Formik initialValues?

Tags: reactjs, use-state, formik

I have a component in my form that stores tags in a useState, but I don't know how to send that array to Formik's initialValues. I need to be able to send that data to the key called "tags" in Formik's initialValues, if someone could help me, thank you very much.

```
const AddProject2 = () => {
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        name: "",
        tags: [],
      }}
      onSubmit={(values) => {
        console.log(values);
      }}
    >
      {() => (
        <Form>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="name">NameProject</label>
            <Field type="text" name="name" />
          </div>

          <ReactTagInput
            placeholder="Write the tags"
            tags={tags}
            onChange={(newTags) => setTags(newTags)}
          />

          <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default AddProject2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just pass your `tags` state from `useState()` into initialValues as shown below, it should work.  This would be shorthand for putting `{name: "", tags: tags}`

```
<Formik
      initialValues={{
        name: "",
        tags,
      }}
      onSubmit={(values) => {
        console.log(values);
      }}
    >
```

-edit-
Regarding the new issue in your comment.

Perhaps it's an issue with the way Formik works.  Looking at their docs, it appears the way to handle control of inputs with formic doesn't directly use onChange, instead you would need to pass in a spread of props with `{...formik.getFieldProps('tags')}`

so:

```
{formik => (
        <Form>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="name">NameProject</label>
            <Field type="text" name="name" />
          </div>

          <ReactTagInput
            placeholder="Write the tags"
            tags={tags}
            {...formik.getFieldProps('tags')}
          />
)}
```

Whether this would be compatible with ReactTagInput, I don't know but it's worth a try.

Comment: Implementing that solution, the array arrives empty. {name: 'Joe', tags: Array(0)}.

Comment: Hmm could there be an issue with `newTags`? Can you show the `ReactTagInput` component?

Comment: mmm It's a library that I used for the tags. You can see it here https://betterstack.dev/projects/react-tag-input/

Comment: I have updated my answer with something that might be helpful

Comment: With that last solution that you offered me, I got an error that said "Formik.getFieldProps is not a function", but I was doing tests and I already found the solution, in fact quite simple, simply in the submit event I add this line, values.tags = tags and just that hahaha. Thank you very much dude for taking the time to collaborate with my issue.